# Reverse animation when exiting hover

Tags: html, css, animation, hover

When hovering over the word it comes out with a smooth animation but when we exit the hover state instead of reversing the animation it just cuts out. How could I make the animation smooth both when entering the hover state and exiting it?

Here is the example:

```css
*{
  font-size: 50px;
}
.container a{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-left: 5%;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
.child{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    display:none;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.container:hover > .child{
    transition: .4s;
    color:#F0C930;
    border-left: 4px solid #F0C930;
    animation: effect .5s;
    display:block;
}
@keyframes effect{
from{
position:relative;
padding-left: 0px;
opacity:0;}
to{
position:relative;
padding-left: 10px;
opacity:1;
    }
}
}
```

```html
<p>hover over "Word"</p>
<div class="container">
  <a>Word</a>
  <div class="child">Word</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Are u sure u want to use animation. Wouldn't transition and transform be better suited for this?

Comment: That was the first idea that came to mind, but I couldn't get transitions to work so I came down to keyframe animations

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CSS `transition` to handle the opacity and padding.
[CSS Transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container .child {
  transition: opacity .5s, padding .5s;
  border-left: 4px solid #F0C930;
  opacity: 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
  color: #F0C930;
}

.container:hover .child {
  opacity: 1;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a>Word</a>
  <div class="child">Word</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Sakumi: Glad you got some direction. Please consider accepting the answer if this helped.